# how to pass a string variable in django urls?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

so i made a variable named urlname in my django model and want to pass it in my urls like this:

```
path('example/<str:url>/', views.example, name='example'),
```

and in my views i did this:

```
def example(request, url):

    example = Example.objects.get(urlname=url)
    context = {'example':example}
    return render(request, 'example/example.html', context)
```

lets say in the models, urlname has the value 'test'.

when i enter the url 'example/test/' in my browser it gives me this error:

> ValueError at /example/test/
> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'test'.
> this is the Example Model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
urlname = models.ForeignKey(urlname,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
name = models.ForeignKey(Topic,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
desc = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='files/examples')

def __str__(self):
    return self.desc[0:50]
```

i've read and checked my code, im pretty new at coding, i hope i get my answer here and my explanation was not unclear.

Comment: Share the `Example` model. Are you sure you used `urlname=...`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `urlname = models.ForeignKey(urlname,..` that seems incorrect

Comment: please post these as answers, not comments

Comment: @Parsa: can you also share the `urlname` model?

Answer (score 0):

In your Example model, you have
`urlname = models.ForeignKey(urlname,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)`

is `urlname` field a FK to model `urlname`?
If so, then in your views line
`example = Example.objects.get(urlname=url)`

You are trying to directly perform get operation on urlname=url, where urlname is an object and url is your string
You should probably perform get operation on some field inside urlname model

so it should be something like
`urlname_<somefield>=url`, where `<somefield>` is a field of the urlname model

Comment: Did this help you fix the issue?